# How do I fix a Parse error [:] in my css?

Tags: css, parse-error

This is the code associated with the assignment I am working on in my web development class. The W3C CSS Validator keeps giving me the following message: "64       Parse Error [:]". What is this and how do I fix it? Please help!

Here is my css:

```
*  {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
         background-color: #ffffff; 
         color: #666666;
         background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
         font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
         background-color: #90c7e3;
         width: 80%; 
         min-width: 700px;
         max-width: 1024px;
         box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
         margin-right: auto;
         margin-left: auto;
}

header {
         background-color: #000033;
         color: #ffffff;
         font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

h1 {
         background-image: url(../images/sunset.jpg);
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: right; 
         padding-left: 20px;
         height: 72px; 
         line-height: 200%;
         margin-bottom: 0;
}

nav {
         float: left;
         width: 160px;
         padding-top: 20px;
         padding-right: 5px;
         padding-left: 20px;
         padding-bottom: 0;
         padding: 5px; 
         font-weight: bold;

}

nav a {
         text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover { 
     color: #ffffff;
}

nav a:link: {
    color: #000033;
}

nav a:visited {
    color: #344873;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

main {
         background-color: #ffffff;
         margin-left: 170px;
         padding-top: 1px;
         padding-bottom: 1px;
         padding-left: 20px;
         padding-right: 20px;
         display: block; 
}

h2 {
         color: #3399cc;
         font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

h3 {
    color: #000033; 
}

dt {
         color: #000033;
         font-weight: bold;
}

.resort {
         color: #000033;
         font-size: 1.2em;
}


#homehero {
         background-image: url(../images/coast.jpg);
         height: 300px;
         background-size: 100% 100%;
         margin-right: 0;
         margin-left: 170px;
         background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

#yurthero {
         background-image: url(../images/yurt.jpg);
         background-size: 100% 100%;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         height: 300px;
         margin-left: 170px;
}

#trailhero {
         background-image: url(../images/trail.jpg);
         height: 300px;
         background-size: 100% 100%;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         margin-left: 170px;
}


footer {
         background-color: #ffffff;
         margin-left: 170px;
         font-size: .70em;
         font-style: italic;
         text-align: center;
         padding: 10px; 
}

header, nav, main, footer {
     display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because of  `nav a:link: {`
Replace it with `nav a:link {`